# run a set of system commands from r

Tags: r, windows, shell, command-line

I have to run the following system command (command line windows) from R console.

```
:Loop
Rscript D:/check.r 2 3 | find "Warning"
if not %errorlevel% equ 0 goto :Loop
echo Connection established
```

I know there is one function `system()` to run system commands, but it takes the command as a string (one command at a time). So, I am not sure how to use it to run my loop command from R? How do I run it from R?

Comment: On Unix systems, you can string multiple commands together on a single line by separating them with semicolons. Maybe there's something similar in Windows?

Comment: @AlexeyShiklomanov Yes, i think we can use `&` to separate commands. But the problem here is we can not use `&` after `:Loop`. So, `:Loop & Rscript D:/check.r 2 3 | find "Error" & if not %errorlevel% equ 0 goto :Loop & echo Connection established ` does not work.

Comment: Not familiar with windows, but why don't put those lines in a file and just execute the file from R?

Comment: @nicola I need to run these 4 lines in a loop for different arguments each time. So, writing these 4 lines again and again in a separate file is not an option. I am currently running these 4 lines in a for loop by passing different args in each iteration in R.

Comment: Not understanding. Why can't you generate the content of the file in each iteration (through `cat` or `writeLines`) and then execute the file?

Comment: @nicola one way to implement your idea is to create a batch file with these 4 lines. Now in R, i can run this file in loop by passing different arguments each time. But how I do this, i.e. pass arguments to a batch file from R and modify the command in the batch file? Do you know?

Comment: @nicola yes, i think i can use `cat` to do this. Thanks, will try it out.